# C++ Sockets Does Not Work Properly

Tags: c++, sockets, flash

back again (sorry)

I've created a socket C++ application, but it isn't working properly.

This is my first code:

```
void Network::Start()
{
    this->socket = Env::GetSocket();

    SOCKADDR_IN sInformation;

    sInformation.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sInformation.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    sInformation.sin_port = htons(30000);

    bind(this->socket, (SOCKADDR*) (&sInformation), sizeof(sInformation));
    listen(this->socket, 10);

    while (true)
    {
        this->DO();
    }
}
```

And the DO function:

```
void Network::DO()
{
    SOCKET s = SOCKET_ERROR;

    sockaddr_in sock_addr;

    accept(s, (sockaddr*) &sock_addr, NULL);

    if (INVALID_SOCKET == s)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Received connection from " << inet_ntoa(sock_addr.sin_addr);
    }
}
```

What happens, always (even if I connect) the value s is INVALID_SOCKET. I connect via a .SWF but it doesn't accept my connection. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to do `s = accept(this->socket...`

Comment: @ctn You should post that as an answer.

Comment: accept does return an integer, not a socket object.

Comment: `accept()` returns a socket descriptor. One some platforms, that is an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing adequate error handling, and you are not using `accept()` correctly.  Try this:

```
void Network::Start()
{
    this->socket = Env::GetSocket();
    if (this->socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        // error
        return;
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN sInformation = {0};

    sInformation.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sInformation.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    sInformation.sin_port = htons(30000);

    if (bind(this->socket, (SOCKADDR*) &sInformation, sizeof(sInformation)) != 0)
    {
        // error
        return;
    }

    if (listen(this->socket, 10) != 0)
    {
        // error
        return;
    }

    while (true)
    {
        this->DO();
    }
}

void Network::DO()
{
    SOCKADDR_IN sock_addr = {0};
    socklen_t sock_addr_len = sizeof(sock_addr);

    SOCKET s = accept(this->socket, (SOCKADDR*) &sock_addr, &sock_addr_len);
    if (INVALID_SOCKET == s)
    {
        return;
    }

    cout << "Received connection from " << inet_ntoa(sock_addr.sin_addr);

    // use s as needed. Don't forget to call close(s) or closesocket(s)
    // when finished, depending on your platform...
}
```

Comment: Now it says the this->socket == INVALID_SOCKET,
    DWORD Env::GetSocket()
    {
     return socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    }

What's wrong with it?

Comment: `socket()` returns a `SOCKET`, not a `DWORD`.  You may need to type-cast if you are getting compiler errors: `return (DWORD) socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);` and `this->socket = (SOCKET) Env::GetSocket();` If you are still having problems, then please provide the **actual error messages**.

Answer (score 1):

[`accept`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/accept) takes the listening socket as a parameter, and *returns* the newly connected socket;

```
socklen_t length = sizeof(sockaddr_in);
s = accept(this->socket, (sockaddr*) &sock_addr, &length);
```

EDIT: Just tested the program, with the socket created with AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM and sInformation cleared out;

```
bzero((char *) &sInformation, sizeof(sInformation));
```

...it seems to be running well on MacOS X and linux.

Comment: No not really, still got the same.

Comment: @x_metal_pride_diamond_x You're passing NULL as the length pointer, I can't find any info on that being supported. Try the edit.

Comment: Still it does not work, since socklen_t is not working I tried change it into int but still it does not work. By the way, there's nothing wrong with the .swf, because with C# it did work.

Comment: Okay when I remove the if/else condition it will just keep on printing:

Received connection from 204.204.204.204

That IP is not even familiar with me,.. :o

Comment: 204 is hex 0xCC. You are getting an IP address of 0xCCCCCCCC. Some compilers use 0xCC for uninitialized memory.